# Executable file run on double click

Tags: c, cygwin, exe

I have written and compiled a program in c using gcc through cygwin, and everything works fine when I run the program from the command line; however, when I double-click the executable file, the command window briefly flashes on the screen, but nothing happens. Any ideas why this could be? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Can it find the libraries it needs? Maybe make a bat file to run it from the correctly location.

Comment: @Bashwork it's running from the same location either way...

Comment: I didn't know if you had copied the executable to another location.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin requires `cygwin.dll` to be in the `PATH` when executing files compiled for that environment. When you compile something with cygwin you are compiling *for* cygwin.

I would recommend using MinGW instead, if you plan on building programs. When you compile something with mingw you are compiling *for* windows.

Comment: You can find out if this is the problem by attempting to run your program form a normal command prompt (not cygwin) and checking for errors.

Comment: But I do have `cygwin.dll` in the path, so what's the problem?

Comment: Then one of the answers below might be your solution. Once a windows application exits the console window is closed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For example you have program that prints "Hello World!" to command line.
It will print "Hello World!" if it's opened from cmd, but if you double click on it, it print it and immediatly close the window.

Try `getch()` to prevent it. It will print "Press any key to continue".

Comment: It doesn't matter to me if the window is immediately closed. All I care about is the result of the program.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile programs inside cygwin, it will link them with dynamic library cygwin.dll. If this file's location is not in your PATH variable, your programs will not run at all outside of cygwin. So, locate cygwin.dll and add that directory to system PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a graphical application?  If not, it's not getting input, so it's probably starting, seeing the EOF (if it checks input at all), then finishing.  When it's finished, the terminal window is closed automatically.